# How to sort 'WindowsPath' object files naturally

Tags: python, glob, pathlib, natsort

I am iterating through files in a directory using Path().glob() and it's not iterating in the correct natural ordering. For eg. it's iterating like this:

```
[WindowsPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P1/dataP1/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P1_Cor.csv'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P10/dataP10/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P10_Cor.csv'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P11/dataP11/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P11_Cor.csv'),
 WindowsPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P12/dataP12/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P12_Cor.csv'),
# ...and so on from P1 to P30
```

When I want it to iterate like this: P1, P2, P3 and so on.

I have tried using the code below but it gives me an error:

```
from pathlib import Path

file_path = r'C:/Users/HP/Desktop'

files = Path(file_path).glob(file)
sorted(files, key=lambda name: int(name[10:]))
```

where 10 is just some trivial number as I am trying out the code.

The error:

```
TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not subscriptable
```

Ultimately, what I want is to iterate through the files and do something with each file:

```
from pathlib import Path

for i, fl in enumerate(Path(file_path).glob(file)):
    # do something
```

I have even tried the library `natsort` but it's not ordering the files correctly in the iteration. I have tried:

```
from natsort import natsort_keygen, ns
natsort_key1 = natsort_keygen(key=lambda y: y.lower())
```

```
from natsort import natsort_keygen, ns
natsort_key2 = natsort_keygen(alg=ns.IGNORECASE)
```

The two codes above still gives me P1, P10, P11 and so on.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: There is no P2, P3, I assume you want P10, P11, P12? Do you want to sort on the file name (eg, P1_Cor.csv) or the earlier directory name (e.g,, `../P1/..`). Do you want to sort numerically (e.g., P2 before P10) or textually?

Comment: Also, if you are globbing r'C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P1/dataP1/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/' then you won't be getting C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P10 and etc...

Comment: Hi @tdelaney, the files I have goes from P1, P2,..., P30 and I want the iteration to iterate in this natural order

Comment: Apologies @tdelaney, I have updated the `file_path` in my question for globbing in the correct directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort by the digits in the file name, you can use the `Path.name` attribute and a regular expression that extracts the digits.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

file_path = r'C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P1/dataP1/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/'

def _p_file_sort_key(file_path):
    """Given a file in the form P(digits)_cor.csv, return digits as an int"""
    return int(re.match(r"P(\d+)", file_path.name).group(1))

files = sorted(Path(file_path).glob("P*_Cor.csv"), key=_p_file_sort_key)
```

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney. Your code is throwing me an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. I am not sure what this error means. If the part inside glob() is a little more complicated (the one I actually have is `'**/P*_' + 'Cor' + '.csv_SAMPLED_NORMALIZED.csv'`, will this affect your code?

Comment: I fixed a bug in `p_file_sort_key` that may explain the type error. Otherwise, make sure its not a different line in your program causing the error. The more complicated glob isn't a problem as long as my assumption that you want to sort on just the final filename without its directory is true. `Path.name` returns the leaf most name and it doesn't matter what directory it happens to be in.

Comment: Your assumption is correct @tdelaney. I tried out your code and it worked, like magic! Once again many thanks and really appreciate this.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble can I ask what does `group()` does here?

Comment: Integers sort differently than strings, so `"2"` is greater than `"10"` even though `2` is less than `10`. In my example, I wanted to sort by the integer so needed some way to get it. The regular expression `r"P(\d+)"` matches the letter "P" followed by some number of digits. The parentheses make the digits the first capture group of the regex and the digits matched are therefore in `group(1)`.

Comment: Its just a guess that you wanted integer sorting. If you don't, then remove the regular expression (and creating the `int`) out.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney. Am I right to say since I have ‘P’ followed by some digits, `group(0)` will capture strings (which is the ‘P’ here) and `group(1)` will capture the digits (which appears after the ‘P’)?

Comment: Not quite. `group(0)` is the full string matched by the regex while groups 1 and following are any capture groups inside the regex. For the string "P10_Cor.csv", group 0 is "P10". Suppose my regex was for the entire file name `r"P(\d+)_Cor\.csv"` (I had to escape the period `\.` because its a special character in a regex) then group 0 would be "P10_Cor.csv" while group 1 would still be "10". Group 0 is there in case you wanted the entire matched string wtihin a larger string.

Comment: Many thanks once again @tdelaney for your explanation on this!

Answer (score 3):

Using `natsort` works to sort this data, but you have to tell it how to extract a string from the `Path` object (it doesn't do it by default for performance purposes).

```
In [2]: from pathlib import Path                                                                                    

In [3]: import natsort                                                                                              

In [4]: a = [Path('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P1/dataP1/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P1_Cor.csv'),
             Path('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P10/dataP10/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P10_Cor.csv'),
             Path('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P2/dataP2/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P2_Cor.csv')]                                                                       

In [5]: natsort.natsorted(a, key=str)                                                                                      
Out[5]: 
[PosixPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P1/dataP1/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P1_Cor.csv'),
 PosixPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P2/dataP2/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P2_Cor.csv'),
 PosixPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P10/dataP10/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P10_Cor.csv')]

In [6]: natsort.natsorted(a, alg=natsort.PATH)
Out[6]: 
[PosixPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P1/dataP1/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P1_Cor.csv'),
 PosixPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P2/dataP2/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P2_Cor.csv'),
 PosixPath('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/P10/dataP10/SAMPLED_NORMALIZED/P10_Cor.csv')]
```

The first option will convert all the `Path` objects to a string which `natsort` knows how to handle. This works for your data.

The second option switches on `natsort`'s `PATH` algorithm, which will automatically handle `Path` objects correctly, and also adds more robust handling for corner-cases common in file system paths.

---

Full disclosure, I am the `natsort` author.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @SethMMorton and thank you for developing `natsort`!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `str` on the Path object or you can use `as_posix()`.

```
from pathlib import Path

for fn in sorted([str(p) for p in Path(file_path).glob('*.csv')]):
    # do something with fn

for fn in sorted([p.as_posix() for p in Path(file_path).glob('*.csv')]):
    # do something with fn
```

Comment: Thanks @Eric Truett. Both didn't work. The first one is giving me ordering: P10, P11, P12 etc. The second one is making any difference to the ordering, ie. it's still P1, P10, P11, P12 etc.